# How do I download an image file from a website using WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I try to download the image from the server. I try so far,

```
use warnings;
use strict; 
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $sequence = "MIPTLAAEPRKPARPPLPVRRESREEPVDAVIVGTGAGGAPLLARLAQAGLKVVALEAGNHWDPAADFATDEREQNKLFWFDERLSAGADPLAFGRNNSGIGVGGSTLHYTAYVPRPQPDDFRLYSDFGVGEDWPIGYGDLEPYFDELECFLGVSGPSPYPWGPARTPYPLAPMPLNAAAQLMARGCAALGLRTSPAANAVLSAPYFQSGVGWRSPCTNRGFCQAGCTTGGKAGMDVTFIPLALAHGAEVRSGAFVTRIETDRAGRVTGVVYVREGREERQRCRTLFLAAGAIETPRLLLLNGLANQSGEVGRNFMAHPGLQLWGQFSEATRPFKGVPGSLISEDTHRPKDADFAGGYLLQSIGVMPVTYATQTARGGGLWGEKLQSHMHGYNHTAGINILGECLPYAHNYLELSDEPDQRGLPKPRIHFSNGKNERRLRDHAEALMRRIWEAAGAQAVWTFERNAHTIGTCRMGADPKRAVVDPEGRAFDVPNLYIIDNSVFPSALSVNPALTIMALSLRTADRFIERTQRGEY";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize -> new;
$mech->get('https://npsa-prabi.ibcp.fr/cgi-bin/npsa_automat.pl?page=/NPSA/npsa_sopma.html');
    $mech->submit_form(
        form_number => 1,
        fields => {
        'notice' => $sequence,
        },
    );


$mech->find_image( alt_regex => qr/.+sopma2.gif/ );
open (FH, ">soi.gif");
binmode (FH);
print FH $mech;
```

The image tag was like this:

```
<img align="TOP" src="/tmp/e3a3c2b34201.sopma2.gif">
```

I already have the link to the image parsed from the website, but I want to download this image. How can I do it?

Comment: Oh. I just understood. You want to save the 2nd of two images in the page, which you already found. But you do not know how to save it. Correct?

Comment: @simbabque Yes i don't know how to save it.. Can you edit my question if you understood..?

Comment: done, and answered :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/libwww-perl-6.13/lib/LWP/Simple.pm) with WWW::Mechanize.

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use LWP::Simple;
my $sequence = "MIPTLAA......";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize -> new;
$mech->get('https://npsa-prabi.ibcp.fr/cgi-bin/npsa_automat.pl?page=/NPSA/npsa_sopma.html');
    $mech->submit_form(
        form_number => 1,
        fields => {
        'notice' => $sequence,
        },
    );

my $cont = $mech->content;  
($img) = $cont =~m/SRC=(.+sopma2\.gif)/g; 
$urL = "https://npsa-prabi.ibcp.fr/$img";
getstore($urL,"soi.gif");
```

`$img` stores the url of the image

Then save the image by using `getstore` method from the `LWP::Simple`

**It is not good idea. See the @simbabque answer.** But it give the result what you need.

Answer (score 3):

The [`find_image` method of WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-find_image) **returns** a [WWW::Mechanize::Image](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Image) object. That only contains the URI, filename and alt tag info about the image, not the content of the image itself. You need to **download** the image file first.

Luckily, you can use your `$mech` for that. The `$image` has [a `URI` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Image#link-URI) that returns the [full URL](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::URL) of that image file. Your [`$mech` can `get`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-get-uri) that image. It comes as a HTTP::Response.

```
my $image = $mech->find_image( url_regex => qr/sopma2\.gif$/ );
my $res = $mech->get($image->URI);

if ($res->is_success) {
  open (my $fh, '>', 'soi.gif') or die $!;
  binmode $fh;
  print $fh $res->decoded_content;
  # no need to close lexical filehandle
}
```

Et voila, there's your image file.

Comment: @simbabqye. Thank you for your answer but it reports error  `Can't call method "URI" on an undefined value`.

Comment: Then it doesn't find the image. I will change the regex in the answer. The `.+` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$mech->get(...)` to store URL content into local file.

```
if( my $image = $mech->find_image( alt_regex => qr/.+sopma2.gif/ )) {
  $mech->get( $img->url, ':content_file' => 'soi.gif');
}
```

[How do i save an image with www::mechanize](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=737473)

`man WWW::Mechanize`

> $mech->find_image()
>          Finds an image in the current page. It returns a WWW::Mechanize::Image object which describes the image.  If it fails to find an image it returns undef.
>   ...
>   $mech->get( $uri )
>          Given a URL/URI, fetches it.  Returns an HTTP::Response object.  $uri can be a well-formed URL string, a URI object, or a WWW::Mechanize::Link object. [...]
>   "get()" is a well-behaved overloaded version of the method in LWP::UserAgent.  This lets you do things like
>   `$mech->get( $uri, ':content_file' => $tempfile );`

Comment: This is the more concise answer. It's a better way than mine. But it currently lacks some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are searching for an image whose alt text contains the string `sopma2.gif`. That image doesn't have an alt text so your program doesn't find it

This program will fetch the gif file that you want. I'm using `url_regex => qr/sopma2/i` to find `sopma2` in the URL instead. That succeeds and returns a `WWW::Mechanize::Image` object. Then all that is necessary is to fetch that objects absolute URL and use `get` with a `:content_file` parameter to save the data to a disk file

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use WWW::Mechanize;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $sequence = "MIPTLAAEPRKPARPPLPVRRESREEPVDAVIVGTGAGGAPLLARLAQAGLKVVALEAGNHWDPAADFATDEREQNKLFWFDERLSAGADPLAFGRNNSGIGVGGSTLHYTAYVPRPQPDDFRLYSDFGVGEDWPIGYGDLEPYFDELECFLGVSGPSPYPWGPARTPYPLAPMPLNAAAQLMARGCAALGLRTSPAANAVLSAPYFQSGVGWRSPCTNRGFCQAGCTTGGKAGMDVTFIPLALAHGAEVRSGAFVTRIETDRAGRVTGVVYVREGREERQRCRTLFLAAGAIETPRLLLLNGLANQSGEVGRNFMAHPGLQLWGQFSEATRPFKGVPGSLISEDTHRPKDADFAGGYLLQSIGVMPVTYATQTARGGGLWGEKLQSHMHGYNHTAGINILGECLPYAHNYLELSDEPDQRGLPKPRIHFSNGKNERRLRDHAEALMRRIWEAAGAQAVWTFERNAHTIGTCRMGADPKRAVVDPEGRAFDVPNLYIIDNSVFPSALSVNPALTIMALSLRTADRFIERTQRGEY";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get('https://npsa-prabi.ibcp.fr/cgi-bin/npsa_automat.pl?page=/NPSA/npsa_sopma.html');

say $mech->res->status_line;
say $mech->title;

$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 1,
    fields => {
      notice => $sequence,
    },
);

say $mech->res->status_line;
say $mech->title;

my $image = $mech->find_image( url_regex => qr/sopma2/i );
my ($file) = $image->url =~ m|([^/]+\z)|;
$mech->get($image->url_abs, ':content_file' => $file);
say "$file saved";
```

### output

```
200 OK
NPS@ : SOPMA secondary structure prediction
200 OK
NPS@ SOPMA secondary structure prediction results
373025433891.sopma2.gif saved
```